# Changing icons using js

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an icons `play/pause` WHen I click `play`, I can see `pause`, but I have many blocks with audio and in my `js` code I can change just first icon(from `play` to `pause`). How can I make it to all my audio elements on the page?

```js
let playIcon = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg";
let pauseIcon = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149670.svg";

function togglePlay(video) {
  var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
  if (!audio)
    return;
  audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  document.getElementById("button").src = audio.paused ? playIcon : pauseIcon;
}
```

```css
#button {
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="player" onclick="togglePlay(this)">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg" id="button">
  <audio>
    <source src="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mp3/bachfugue.mp3" />
  </audio>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the ID to get the button, but access it relatively to the element that calls the function. Try this function.

```
function togglePlay(elm) {
  var audio = elm.querySelector('audio');
  if(!audio) return;

  audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  elm.querySelector('img').src = audio.paused ? playIcon : pauseIcon;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice setup that should do the trick:

```js
let playIcon = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg";
let pauseIcon = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149670.svg";

function togglePlay(video) {
  var audio = video.querySelectorAll("audio")[0];
  if (!audio)
    return;
  audio.paused ? audio.play() : audio.pause();
  video.querySelectorAll(".button")[0].src = audio.paused ? playIcon : pauseIcon;
}
```

```css
.button {
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="player" onclick="togglePlay(this)">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg" class="button">
  <audio>
    <source src="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mp3/bachfugue.mp3" />
  </audio>
</div>
<div class="player" onclick="togglePlay(this)">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg" class="button">
  <audio>
    <source src="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mp3/bachfugue.mp3" />
  </audio>
</div>
<div class="player" onclick="togglePlay(this)">
  <img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149668.svg" class="button">
  <audio>
    <source src="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mp3/bachfugue.mp3" />
  </audio>
</div>
```